# Is it possible to deselect freestyle edges?

Tags: rendering, materials, freestyle

Is it possible to deselect freestyle edges?

For example, I enabled *Material Boundary* in *Render layers → Freestyle Line Set → Edge Types* to draw lines on all edges between faces with different materials:

[image]

[image]

Is it possible to explicitly exclude an edge from freestyle drawing so I can have all material boundary edges drawn except for ones I specify?

e.g:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. In *Edit Mode* select the edge and [*Mark Freestyle Edge*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Freestyle/Parameter_Editor/Line_Set#Edge_Marks) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>,<kbd>F</kbd>
2. In the *Properties* window > *Render Layers* > *Freestyle Line Set*:

   - Enable *Logical AND*.
   - Enable *Edge Mark* and the (Exclude Edge marks) X button next to it.
     [image]

### Result:

[image]

Comment: For some reason it does not work for me. Nothing seems to be drawn with logical AND enabled?

Comment: @gandalf3 I've [uploaded the blend](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/23814) used to create the above image for you to inspect. I suspect you have additional edge types enabled, in that case you can stick with _Logical OR_ and enable _Exclude edge material boundary_ (X button).

Comment: Thanks, using OR works. Though I'm still confused as to why AND was not working. As far as I can tell, the settings are identical to your example, but when I tried it, [this](http://www.pasteall.org/pic/58667) was what was drawn. Here is my [.blend file](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/23830)

Comment: In your file, the top and backside faces have the same material assigned, so there's no material boundary edge being drawn.