# What could cause these lines in Freestyle Rendering?

Tags: modifiers, freestyle

Ubuntu 18.04

Blender 2.91

Skill level: near pathetic

I have a simple shape I'm trying to freestyle and it is rendering extra lines it shouldn't. I've seen [this bug](https://developer.blender.org/T36350) and it's not the same, my simple object can be duplicated as below. I've also fiddled about with the freestyle settings a lot and can't seem to eliminate it with any of the settings. I imagine I'm going to have to apply edge marks [as shown here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34357/how-do-i-make-freestyle-ignore-a-specific-edge-material-or-object). **The question** is why this is happening (AKA am I doing something wrong?)

To replicate, no other tweaks or settings outside of what is mentioned below, new unsaved blend:

- Create a simple cylinder, I used 12" X 2" x 2", rotate 90 degrees Y axis.
- Create a second cylinder smaller than the first, 1" x 1" x 4", rotate vertically, both cylinders oriented at 0/0/0
- Confirm all normals recalculated outside on both
- Use the second cylinder to apply a boolean modifier to the first, punching a hole in the first cylinder
- Set up freestyle with a .5px or 1px line
- Render in Eevee or Cycles (result is the same)

What I get is random lines that don't appear to be related to the mesh.

[image: From am Eevee Render]

At first I thought it was because the vertices of the second cylinder don't "line up" with the first, played around with it and it doesn't appear to be the case. Here is a cap of the edit mode and wireframe, in this one the vertices alternate but there are no stray vertices or edges, it should work fine (???)

[image: edit mode and wireframe]

I will probably forge on with Freestyle Edge Mark, which will be a bit tedious in the actual project. Can anyone shed insight as to why this may be happening?

**EDIT:** Per the comments below, I've uploaded a version of this
[image]

The interesting thing, this one is only showing a line inside the "hole" as opposed to the additional line along the length as in my original screen captures. Seems to indicate something different in the creation of the two cylinders (????)

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing your actual project, but my guess is that it's the boolean operation that's causing this. Booleans are notorious for creating bad topology (n-gon's and whatnot), as well as often needing to "cut into" flat faces in order to facilitate their placement. These things can cause all sorts of unwanted effects, including shading errors, and "ghost edges". If you want us to have a closer look at your actual project to find out what's actually going on, you can upload it here - https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Thanks, it's created as above so it will only take a few minutes to create a new one. Once the boolean is applied, the mesh looks clean as above.

Comment: Thanks again, done - but see "edit" notes above. In creating this one, only the line inside the hole is showing. This seems to say it's the initial faces of the two objects. I think. Maybe. LOL

[<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=YE7ZlXvX" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/YE7ZlXvX/)

Comment: Looking at your project, this one seemed to be caused by some duplicate vertices. Select the whole thing in edit mode, then press M (merge), and select "by distance". Then try rendering again.